add Firebase to a Flutter Windows Desktop
i have a Flutter desktop app and i want to add authentication to it and i search for the Firebase packages and i found some of them support windows like these packages :
firebase_core: ^3.8.0  & cloud_firestore: ^5.5.0
&  firebase_storage: ^12.3.6   &  firebase_auth: ^5.3.3
so that i tried to add Firebase to my project and initialize it like this :
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:try_auth/Pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:try_auth/firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.windows,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

then run the project on the current platform (windows) ,i get this error :
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
cmake -E tar: error: ZIP decompression failed (-5)
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:119 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    G:/New folder/Flutter/Flutter Projects/try_auth/build/windows/x64/extracted/firebase_cpp_sdk_windows

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_app".

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_app

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_auth".

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_auth

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_storage".

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_storage

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_firestore".

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_firestore

Error: Unable to generate build files

Exited (1).

edit: when i run the project on chrome it works well without any error

What kind of authentication, btw?

@DevQt  Firebase Email/Password Authentication

Kindly confirm my answer if it suits your case.

If you solely targeting Firebase authentication API for Flutter (Windows Desktop), kindly refer to this documentation.
So, to resolve your issue:
Please uninstall these plugins (unless you know how to use them), such as firebase_core, cloud_firestore, and firebase_storage plugins (some of them could introduce issues with your setting up process if it wasn't handled correctly).
To proceed using Firebase authentication API, retain the firebase_auth plugin and follow the documentation on the link.
Note: Before to proceed, perform:
flutter pub get
flutter pub clean

PS: I hope you install the plugin using flutter pub add <plugin_name>
I hope it helps!
